# Web Browser Navigation WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, browser

I have a problem when i try to send the URL to the browser as a tag of a Button. Look what I'm doing:

```
<Button Content="101" Tag="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" Width="446" Click="Button_Click" />
```

Navigate to browser page:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(
                new Uri("/webbrowser.xaml?path=" +
                        HttpUtility.UrlEncode((sender as Button).Tag.ToString()),
                        UriKind.Absolute));
        }
```

On webbrowser.xaml I have:

```
 <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="MiniBrowser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
IsGeolocationEnabled="True"  IsScriptEnabled="True" Width="456" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
```

and on webbrowser.xaml.cs :

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string path = "";

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("path", out path))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
                {
                    MiniBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute));

                }
            }
        }
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? Becose when I press the button i have Debuger.Break(); :-(

Comment: Well, you can always read what the Visual Studio is saying to you and you are in better position to see what the actual error is and how to fix it. We would have to create a new project, replicate your project structure and then run your code just to see the error which you can easily read out from Visual Studio.

Comment: here you go:
> PivotApp1.DLL!PivotApp1.App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 125 C#

Comment: And what is the error? that is merely a location which is the default location for *all* unhandled exceptions.

Comment: System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Error.CallApplicationUEHandler(System.Exception e) Unknown
  System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.Error.IsNonRecoverableUserException(System.Exception ex, out uint xresultValue) Unknown
  System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(System.IntPtr unmanagedObj, System.IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, int argsTypeIndex, int actualArgsTypeIndex, string eventName) Unknown

Comment: Does your code ever hit the last snippet you posted? Can you put a breakpoint there and go line by line and find out which line causes the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I think , there is no need to encode it while passing and if it is compulsary kindly decode it while passing to browser